# Autocomplete form with ajax not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, autocomplete

http://jsfiddle.net/p8jthubw/

I modified [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp) autocomplete form so that a hidden field with id gets added to the form when a selection is made from the autocomplete suggestions in my form as you can see in the above fiddle. I also have a select input next to it whose choices should be based on what is selected in the first box using an ajax request.

My problem is, if there are more than one suggestion for a given input to the autocomplete field, the id for the last suggestion gets automatically filled to the hidden field, and will also be used for the ajax request for the next field.

So I moved the call to the ajax function to inside the function `b.addEventListener("click", function(e)` so that it gets called only when the value is selected from the suggestions, but in this case, no value is getting passed as POST data. So it returns nothing:

```
b.addEventListener("click", function(e)
{
    c = document.getElementById("customerid");
    c.setAttribute("value", arr2[i]);
    $('#customerid').change();
    inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
    closeAllLists();
});
```

Output:

```
<input value="undefined" name="customerid" id="customerid" type="hidden">
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using W3schools though

Comment: @AkintundeOlawale Are there any better ways to implement the autocomplete feature? I thought it was the easiest to implement into my project. It worked but I never checked cases where there are multiple suggestions for the same input which is causing problems now.

Comment: You cannot have your listener to the input... Fire the event to when you select the choice

Comment: @CarlosAlvesJorge Hi Carlos, could you check the edit, I added the portion so that the event is called when I click on the selection, but then, the value is being set as 'undefined'.